# Difference comparing dates in MariaDB and MySQL

Tags: mysql, datetime, mariadb

I have two servers using the same app with similar data. The app is trying to launch a query to retrieve some records, using some dates as condition.

Let say we have this data:

| ID | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-14 |
| 2 | 2021-07-15 |

And we try this query in each system.

System A - 10.1.48-MariaDB-0+deb9u2:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date >= '2021-07-14 00:00:00' AND start_date < '2021-07-14 24:00:00'
```

It doesn't return anything

System B - MySQL Community Server (GPL) 5.7.32:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date >= '2021-07-14 00:00:00' AND start_date < '2021-07-14 24:00:00'
```

It returns:

| ID | start_date |
| --- | --- |
| 1 | 2021-07-14 |

I have also tried removing the time "00:00:00" but same behaviour.

I suppose there would be a configuration Global Variable that I could change so it has the same result.

I would like NOT to change the query, if possible.

Any idea?

Thanks in advance

Comment: `'2021-07-14 24:00:00'` is not a valid datetime value. Did you try `'2021-07-15 00:00:00'` instead?

Comment: With '2021-07-15 00:00:00' it works, but I would like to use the same query, I am not able to change it. Why in MySQL is working and MariaDB no? Is it something we can change through configuration?

Comment: Change to `'2021-07-15 00:00:00'` and use this query in both systems.

Comment: I can't do that. It's not my code, I can't change it

Comment: Compare `select @@sql_mode;` for the two servers.  Also do `show warnings;` immediately after the queries and see what that says

Comment: MySQL 5 is quite old (current version at time of writing is 8.0.25) - I wonder if the code that works on v5 would still work under v8? Fixing it now might be saving you grief later under MySQL anyway.

Comment: the invalid date is a problem with v8 too

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should change the query. You are suggesting that '2021-07-14 24:00:00' and '2021-07-15 00:00:00' represent the same value.
Try using this instead:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE start_date >= '2021-07-14 00:00:00' AND start_date <= '2021-07-14 23:59:59'
```

You could also reduce number of literals in your query:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE DATE(start_date) = '2021-07-14'
```

Comment: You say it is not your code, you can't change it, but you need to escalate to have it changed by someone. 24:00:00 is wrong.

Comment: I understand then that for MySQL the query works, and for MariaDB it doesn't work. And there isn't any option to bring the same behaviour. I'll scalate it to change the code. Thanks all!